# In ui-select how to select all child and sub-child categories when parent category is clicked?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, admin-panel

I have a field with ui-select for categories in my custom form.

I have this piece of code in ui_component form for generating the ui-select

```
  <field name="categories">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                 <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Product\Form\Categories\Options</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Categories</item>
                    <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">field</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/ui-select</item>
                    <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">categories</item>
                    <item name="filterOptions" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="showCheckbox" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="disableLabel" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="chipsEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="multiple" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="levelsVisibility" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">50</item>
                     <item name="tooltip" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="description" xsi:type="string">Select the categories.</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>

                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
```

Which gives the the ui-select field with categories loaded in tree view.

The problem i am facing is, 
[image]

example::

when i select gear parent, the child categories are not auto selected by default.

How do i do this? ie. **Auto select all child categories when parent category is selected, and uncheck all when parent category is unchecked.** I need this in **backend form**.
Any suggestion is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible out of the box.
I don't have a solution, but I have an idea.
The js file that handles the category tree is `vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/form/element/ui-select.js`.
You can try to create your own component that extends the original one.
The magic happens in the function `toggleOptionSelected`.
This function accepts as parameter an object `data` where `data.optgroup` is an object containing all the child nodes.

You can try to override this function and in the section

```
if (!isSelected) { /*eslint no-lonely-if: 0*/
    this.value.push(data.value);
}
```

add your code that loops through data.optgroup and makes all the nodes selected.

Answer (score 0):

Override below file

vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/form/element/ui-select.js

replace below function

```
toggleOptionSelected: function (data) {
            var self = this;
            var isSelected = this.isSelected(data.value);
        
            if (this.lastSelectable && data.hasOwnProperty(this.separator)) {
                return this;
            }
        
            if (!this.multiple) {
                if (!isSelected) {
                    this.value(data.value);
                }
                this.listVisible(false);
            } else {
                if (!isSelected) { /*eslint no-lonely-if: 0*/
                    this.value.push(data.value);
                    /* to add current category and callled recursive function for selecting parent category*/
                    $.each(data.optgroup, function( key, values ) {
                        self.value.push(values.value);
                        if (typeof values.optgroup !== 'undefined') {
                            self.childToParentIterate(values,'add');
                        }
                    });
                    if (typeof data.optgroup === 'undefined') {
                        self.childToParentIterate(data,'add');
                    }
        
                } else {
                    this.value(_.without(this.value(), data.value));                    
                    $.each(data.optgroup, function( key, optval ) {
                        self.value.pop(optval.value);
                        var optgroup = optval.optgroup;
                        self.childRemove(optgroup);
                    });
                }
            }
```

Add below functions

```
childRemove: function(optgroup){
            var self = this;
            $.each(optgroup, function( key,val ) {
                self.value.pop(val.value);
                self.childRemove(val.optgroup);
            });
        },

childToParentIterate: function(data, op){
            var self = this;        
            var path = data.path;
            var level = data.level;
            $.each(data.optgroup, function( key, value ) {
                var optgroup = value.optgroup;
                self.value.push(value.value);
                    $.each(optgroup, function( optkey,optval ) {
                        var label = optval.label;
                            if(op == "add")
                            {
                                self.value.push(optval.value);
                            }
                        self.childIteration(optval,op,level,path);
                    });
            });
        },
        
        childIteration: function(data, op,level,path){        
            var self = this;        
            if(data.level < level){
                var optgroup = data.optgroup;
                $.each(optgroup, function( optkey,optval ) {
                    var label = optval.label;         
                        if(op == "add")
                        {                           
                            self.value.push(optval.value);
                        }                  
                    self.childIteration(optval,op,level,path);
                });
            }
        }
```